Connector between ENT and regular conduit
I bought a house that needs a lot of electrical updates, but can't do them all at once.
There is a disconnect at the well house, 170 feet from the main panel. Only 2 hots are coming from the main panel, and there is no ground, no neutral. The disconnect is grounded in itself (old metal box).
I am adding a small subpanel, but I have some difficulty getting the right parts between the indoor panel to the eaves and getting the wires (6 gauge, I think).
As far as I know, I can get the feed through a flexible ENT conduit. So (from the panel) I have the right part for the panel (with the plastic to protect the cable), then the flexible tube, and then I need to go through the siding. This connection between the flexible conduit and the rigid is a problem for me.
Thank you for your time.
The subpanel and the disconnect to the right:

The eaves with the cable from the main panel:

EDIT.
I will treat this subpanel as if it were the main service. Service drop from aerial cable, 10 feet from the ground, 18 inches from the bottom of the cable to the roof, etc.
My final question would be if PVC 40 is adequate (since I have all the parts for this) or if it needs to be metal rigid conduit.
image source: https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/wiring/installing-an-electrical-service


When it comes to electricity, there is no "I think"  There is only I know or I will find out/ask.  If 6 gauge, then it is probably larger than the minimum required, which is good.  Most well pumps do not need 40 or 50 amps(6 gauge common use).  You want to check what the well pump requires in amps(probably quite hard now) and the breaker size feeding it.  Can/should add ground rods to the well house.  Neutral is not really needed if pump is 240 volts.

"connection between the flexible conduit and the rigid is a problem..." Your post does not mention any conduit other than ENT, so it leaves one guessing at what you mean. Please edit more detail into your post, and clarify your single specific question, if you mean to get the best answer. As for connecting ENT to Rigid Conduit (thick- walled steel conduit pipe that can be threaded for making connections), one would generally use an ENT connector that has male threads and connect to Rigid using a threaded coupling.

What's the purpose of adding the subpanel?  Also, is that messenger wire hooked up to anything at the main panel end?

@crip659 : Well is 30 amps, 240 v.

@ThreePhaseEel : I need to have extra outlets for water filtration, one for me to work in the area, etc. Now, just the well has power.

@JimmyFix-it : schedule 40 conduit. Trying to figure out the route from the connector (between ENT and the rigid conduit) to the insulated connecter connecting the cables from the main panel to the new cables from the subpanel).

@crip659 : yes, I am adding a copper stick. Will connect the neutral to the aluminum that holds the cables in the air (poles).

@user2060451 is replacing that aerial cable in the cards?  Also, is the pipe from the pumphouse to the main house metal or plastic, and how many HP is the well pump itself?

@ThreePhaseEel: I will replace the aerial cable in a year. That is a big job, digging 170 feet, plus the cable. and then I also need to replace the main panel...
Not sure about the HP. The electrical part is 240v/30 amp fuses.
The main panel to well is on the air exclusively.

@user2060451 I was asking about the water pipe from the well to the house, whether it is metal or plastic

@ThreePhaseEel, from what I see, PVC. Maybe there is a galvanized in the middle, but it seems to be all PVC.
After spending hours on this, I will treat this as a feeder from the utility company (except it is from the main panel with aerial cable and service drop. I will add an image in the post.
